# Adding Checkout with PayPal using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, paypal, paypal-ipn

I used the wizard on this site: https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php to integrate "Checkout with PayPal" in my website, using Classic ASP.

However, I get this error when I click on the button "checkout with paypal":

> 10002 Security error
>
> Security header is not valid
>
> Error

I already have a shopping cart I have built, and I want to add the button checkout with PayPal to it. This is the first time I've tried to integrate PayPal into my shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago and you probably already have a solution, but I had this same error and it turned out that I wasn't using the correct username and password. I was using my Paypal username and password, but it should be the API username and password.  Also be aware that there are different credentials for both sandbox and LIVE.

Of course, if I'm telling you things you already know, I do apologise.

Comment: If it were not for your answer, this post should have been deleted since it would have no content at all. (it does have a pretty good google ranking)